# LinkedIn siteStandardProfileRequest URLS no longer valid

Tags: linkedin-api

We use the LinkedIn API to retrieve the profile URL for our users using OAuth2.

Once we get the response from LinkedIn we store the  siteStandardProfileRequest URL field in our app so other users can check the profile.

However we've seen that some of the URLs get 404's. The culprit URLs tend to have a numeric ID, while the other URLs are alphanumeric.

Is there a way to convert the numeric URLs to their alphanumeric counterparts without having to get an authorization token from the original user? Or generate valid URLs from what we have?

Thanks!