# Link to LinkedIn profile stopped working

Tags: linkedin-api

I used to link to users LinkedIn profiles using
`https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=ID_OF_THE_USER`

This worked until now... now I get "Page not found" for every user.

Does anyone know whether or not this is temporary? Or did LinkedIn change something? I can't seem to find anything on their website.

**Update:**
I contacted LinkedIn: summary of the conversation is in the answer below.

Comment: Works for me and my profile (id=AAMAABlBapEBCtQejAWf1xTs4RCFa04UXc1rOC0). Did you check the Id and verified going to the url manually?

Comment: Your link doesnt work when I click it. I don't get the page not found though, but an "unforseen error". Also, the IDs I put in the URL are numeric.

Comment: Can you share one of the IDs?

Comment: Example link with real ID: https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=99376404

Comment: Not working. Is this a api id or a public id?

Comment: Not sure. My client has these IDs in their database, not sure how they gathered them. Link above used to work until now...

Comment: Ask your query to https://developer.linkedin.com/. They might be able to help you

Comment: I tried contacting LinkedIn. Updated my question. Didn't get much wiser...

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756659/linkedin-sitestandardprofilerequest-urls-no-longer-valid, but still no answer :(

And seeing the response you got I'm not quite sure they understood the problem.

I'm aware users are free to change their profile URL's still I think the appropriate behavior is that it shouldn't break the URL we've got from their API.

Comment: @GuillermoRomero: got a mail back from LinkedIn: added it as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted LinkedIn, here's a brief summary:

**LinkedIn**: *We did recently change how this format is listed. We're sorry for the inconvenience. Information for the vanity url can be located here: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/87?query=vanity%20url  Thanks for your interest. I hope this helps!*

**Me**: *So, is it correct to say that it has become impossible to go to a profile based on an ID alone?*

**LinkedIn**: *That is correct. Most individuals will be using a vanity profile url. We're sorry for the inconvenience.*

I guess we'll have to look for the vanity URL from now on.

Comment: How did you manage to contact them directly? I have the same problem for some users, even using the vanity URL. I tried to get in touch with their support, but they only redirected me here...

Comment: I used Facebook chat.

Comment: Sorry but this is no answer... I asked people to create a vanity url on purpose... still not working, even directly on the linkedin website... https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile
I am pretty sure there is a bug in their new plugin version...

Comment: It still not working for me. I have also tried others, for example Bill Gates' profile (linkedin.com/in/williamhgates) and it does not working either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the item of "Your profile's public visibility" on your profile page as well. You should turn it on if you want your public link work.
Bests

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue when linking to an LinkedIn profile from my website, where the browser informed me that this is against a security policy.
What worked for me as a solution is to add the following code to my html link:

```
target = "_blank"
```

This opens the linked LinkedIn page in a new tab and it seems to work without any issues.